# Journal Name not italicized in rmarkdown pdf

Tags: r-markdown, rstudio, csl

I have recently updated my RStudio. The new RStudio version is 2022.12.0.

Then I have knitted an old manuscript of mine in pdf, but now in bibliography, the journal name is not italicized. Here are my YAML (a little edited for privacy). Before the update, there was no such issue.

I use Zotero to create my bib file. Also if I export reference from zotero to word file, then there is no issue as well regarding Journal name italics.

```
---
title: |
  | \vspace{2cm} THE MANUSCRIPT TITLE 
subtitle: 
author: 

date:


abstract: | 
  \justify ABABBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBB
BBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBB
  
  &nbsp;
  &nbsp;

  
  |
  `r kableExtra::text_spec ("Keywords:", bold = TRUE)` A; B; C.  
  
    &nbsp;
    &nbsp;
  
  |
  `r kableExtra::text_spec ("JEL Classifications:", bold = TRUE)` C, Y. 
  
  &nbsp;  
  &nbsp;  
  
  <p>&nbsp;</p>  
  <p>&nbsp;</p>  
  
  |
   
output: 
    bookdown::pdf_document2:
    fig_caption: yes  
keep_tex: yes   
header-includes:
    - \pagenumbering{gobble}
    - \usepackage[document]{ragged2e}
    - \usepackage{sectsty} \sectionfont{\centering \emph}
    - \usepackage{lscape}
    - \newcommand{\blandscape}{\begin{landscape}}
    - \newcommand{\elandscape}{\end{landscape}}
    - \usepackage{xcolor}

link-citations: yes
linkcolor: blue
geometry: "left=2.75cm,right=2.75cm,top=2.5cm,bottom=2.5cm"
fontsize: 12pt
citecolor: blue
urlcolor: blue
toc: false 
bibliography: reference_case.bib
---
```

Comment: Nothing obvious, but two comments:
a) You'll generally get better output if you set your bibliography to use CSL JSON, which you can generate from Zotero -- that's the native format with which CSL works
b) Try specifying the CSL style using something like `csl: apa`. Knitting should default to Chicago author-date, which does italicize journals, but always better to be sure.

Comment: @adam.smith I have created bibliography using CSL JSON from Zotero and also use `csl: apa.csl`, but journals name still not italicized. Not sure what is going on. Thanks

Comment: I have been able to fix the issue by reinstalling the tinytex. The code is - `tinytex::reinstall_tinytex(repository = "illinois")`. Thanks